# Creating new dataframe with missing value

Tags: r

i have a dataframe structured like this

```
time <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2)
group <- c('a','b','c','d','c','d')
number <- c(2,3,4,1,2,12)

df <- data.frame(time,group,number)

  time group number
1    1     a      2
2    1     b      3
3    1     c      4
4    1     d      1
5    2     c      2
6    2     d     12
```

in order to plot the data i need it to contain the values for each group (from a-d) at each time interval, even if they equal zero. so a data frame looking like this:

```
 time group number
1    1     a      2
2    1     b      3
3    1     c      4
4    1     d      1
5    2     a      0
6    2     b      0
7    2     c      2
8    2     d     12
```

any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid` and `merge`, like this:

```
> merge(df, expand.grid(lapply(df[c(1, 2)], unique)), all = TRUE)
  time group number
1    1     a      2
2    1     b      3
3    1     c      4
4    1     d      1
5    2     a     NA
6    2     b     NA
7    2     c      2
8    2     d     12
```

From there, it's just a simple matter of replacing `NA` with 0.

Comment: I was getting there, but would have needed another 10-20 minutes, and it would have been multi line.

Comment: An example for the final step would be: `rdf[is.na(rdf$number),]$number = 0`  if `rdf` had the result of the `merge` command.

Comment: @MikeWise Kiss, `rdf[is.na(rdf)] <- 0`

Comment: @MikeWise, I also like the `replace` function in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
new <- merge(df, expand.grid(lapply(df[c(1, 2)], unique)), all.y = TRUE)
new[is.na(new$number),"number"]  <- 0
new
```